# How to solve issue with source code in glitch?

Tags: google-chrome, aframe

I was trying to see the source code of this website so that I could experiment with it.

https://supermedium.com/superframe/components/audioanalyser/examples/volume/

So, using the 'view page source' option (right click), I copy-pasted the code into https://glitch.com/. Unfortunately, it didn't do any of the animation or audio! Could anyone please help? I have a project coming up soon and it would be really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

copy-pasting will not work mainly because of these lines:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="../build.js"></script>
  <script src="../components/audioanalyser-volume-scale.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
```

those are relative paths that won't be pointing to the correct resources. You would need to recreate the folder structure and include those files or rewrite it so it is accessible

Comment: Hello Piotr, thank you for your comment. This is great advice that I have used in my project. Unfortunately, the audio and animation still seems to not be working. Thank you again for your advice.